# Start activity after finish current

Tags: java, android, admob, android-recyclerview

I need to complete three task in one button click. its look like on button click called SaveQuote
1) Hide Adview
2) Make Screenshot of Layout and Save it
3) Show Adview

Now I have implemented method for do above three task in my java as like below

```
else if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.save_image) {
                        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        saveQuote();
                        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But I am facing issue that ad always staying visible. If I use on ViewGone method and saveQuote method than its working fine, but if I add VISIBLE method than its not hiding my adview.

Note : I am not getting any error for same. I just need to know how can I achieve above three task via one button click

My saveQuote method is like below

```
private void saveQuote(){
    String id=getQuote(mItemIndx).get(KEY_ID);
    View v1=null;

    List<Fragment> activeFragments=getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    for(Fragment fragment:activeFragments){

        QuoteCard cardFrag=(QuoteCard)fragment;
        if(cardFrag!=null&&cardFrag.mId.equals(id)){
            v1=cardFrag.getCardView();

        }
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView)v1.findViewById(R.id.textAuthorSign);
    textView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().saveQuoteImage(bitmap);
    Snackbar.make(v1,"Quote Saved",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I am getting error like below if set VISIBLE method on end of saveQuote

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

Thanks

Comment: what are you doing on your saveQuote(); please post code here.

Comment: You are changing adView visibility back to visible. Remove that code if you want adView to stay hidden.

Comment: I do not want keep it hidden, I want back visible after take screenshot.

Comment: View.GONE and View.VISIBLE  will not work like that .Make a delay between those 2.

Comment: Hi ! @sunilsunny , Can you please tell me how can I do it ?

Comment: final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
         adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 5000);

Comment: reduce the delay if you don't want that much

Comment: @RajubhaiRathod did you tried it ?

Comment: just make your view visible after you are done with saveQuote();

Comment: I have already put it after saveQuote();

Comment: @RajubhaiRathod just try my last comment.. you will be able to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
saveQuote();
```

now in your saveQuote() method after all your logic is set.. add last line..

**`adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`** make note that your adView should be defined globally and you have initialized your adVIew.

Comment: I Have tried this before also and again now, I am getting " Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback " as well " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference " Error if I do like this.

Comment: please post your saveQuote() code. so that i can help and please post your complete error log. the errror you are getting is may be because of adview Initialization.

Comment: @RajubhaiRathod also make sure u have initialized your adView variable, before using it.

Comment: just add this line adVIew  = (viewtype )findViewById(R.id.idOfAdVIew); after your setContentVIew() method.

Comment: because a null pointer exception on view is only raised when its not initialized after defined in xml.

Answer (score 0):

You should review "Handle,Looper,Message"

`adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        saveQuote();
        adView.post(runable)
        Runnable runable=new Runnable(){
          @Override
           public void run(){
               adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }`

Comment: I am getting error like " runable cannot be resolved to a variable "

Answer (score 0):

Declare as global

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Change your code like this

```
      else if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.save_image) {
                                    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    saveQuote();
                                      handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                     { @Override public void run() { 
 adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } }, 5000); 
                    }
```

Here the delay is 5 s reduce the delay if don't need that much.

Comment: HI ! I am getting error like "**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference**" Thanks

Comment: Which means you have not initialized adView .

Comment: @sunilsunny thats the only case.. he has not initialized his view. thats why he is getting null pointer exception